# C# Perda de Precisão Tipo Double

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo

Olá! Escrevi um programa em C# que converte o separador decimal de uma string de vírgula para ponto.
Para isso, eu utilizei o método Replace().
O problema ocorre quando eu tento converter o número (agora com ponto decimal) para o tipo double.
Ocorre uma espécie de perda de precisão.
Por exemplo, se eu tenho uma string com o conteúdo 3,14 e tento converter para o tipo double, após a conversão o separador decimal se perde e obtenho 314 como resultado.
Código exemplar:

```
using System;

namespace Testes {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string numero = "3,14";
            double valor;

            valor = double.Parse(numero.Replace(',', '.')); //Substitui o ponto pela vírgula
            Console.WriteLine("O valor após a conversão é {0}.", valor); 
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

O que eu quero é que após a conversão de double para string, o valor decimal não se perca.
Já tentei utilizar casting mas não deu certo.
Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?
Obrigado!

Comment: Pode colocar a sua saida por favor. Fiz o teste aqui e minha saída foi : `O valor após a conversão é 3.14.`

Comment: A resposta atendeu o que foi perguntado? Ficou algo pendente?

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece por causa deste ajuste de substituir a vírgula por ponto. O código da pergunta não considera a cultura da aplicação e isso pode ser um grande problema (assim como agora).

O que acontece aí é que a cultura da sua aplicação não é nenhuma cultura que use o ponto como separador de decimais. Muito provavelmente a aplicação está usando a cultura português já que isso é inferido do Sistema Operacional.

A não ser que você tenha um alto controle sobre a entrada dos dados, a melhor forma de fazer esta conversão é forçar a cultura na operação.

A entrada separa decimais com vírgula, é possível usar a cultura como português. O método [`double.Parse` tem uma sobrecarga](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse) que permite que isso seja feito.

```
double.Parse(numero, new CultureInfo("pt"));
```

Um outro problema comum que você poderá encontrar é que o `double.Parse` vai estourar uma exceção sempre que não conseguir fazer a conversão. Uma boa alternativa é usar o  [`double.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse). Ele também tem uma sobrecarga que permite informar o formato desejado da entrada da conversão. Abaixo um exemplo de uso:

```
if(!double.TryParse(entrada, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, new CultureInfo("pt"), out _)) {
    WriteLine($"Valor {entrada} é inválido");
}
```

Em ambos os casos ainda é possível usar o [**`NumberStyles`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles) para definir detalhes da conversão.

---

Código funcional fazendo conversões em diferentes culturas

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using static System.Console;

class MainClass 
{
    private static readonly CultureInfo CulturaEntrada = new CultureInfo("pt");

    public static void Main (string[] args) 
    {
        // Note que, dependendo da cultura que está aqui, a conversão pode ou não falhar
        FazerConversao();

        // Aqui, é garantido que funcione a sua conversão vai falhar
        // porque o separador de decimal da cultura é vírgula e não ponto
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt");
        FazerConversao();

        // Este método é independente da cultura da aplicação
        // Usando PT, EN ou FR a conversão sempre vai funcionar
        FazerConversaoCorretamente();

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
        FazerConversaoCorretamente();

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr");
        FazerConversaoCorretamente();
    }

    public static void FazerConversao(string entrada = "3,14") 
    {
        double valor = double.Parse(entrada.Replace(',', '.'));
        ImprimirResultado(valor);
    }

    public static void FazerConversaoCorretamente(string entrada = "3,14") 
    {
        if(!double.TryParse(entrada, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CulturaEntrada, out var valor)) {
            WriteLine($"Valor {entrada} é inválido");
            return;
        }

        ImprimirResultado(valor);
    }

    private static void ImprimirResultado(double valor) 
    {
        WriteLine($"O valor após a conversão é {valor}.");
        WriteLine($"A cultura sendo usada é {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture}\n");
    }
}
```